# JQuery Ajax bad request on wordpress theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress, widget

I created a custom widget to display a calendar and the code for the calendar can be found [here](https://phppot.com/jquery/creating-web-calendar-in-php-using-jquery-ajax/).

From my theme root directory, the folder structure looks like this:
inc/most-recent-widget.php

All the calendar code has been added in the widget class:

```
class __themename_Most_recent_widget extends WP_Widget{

    private $weekDayName = array ("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN");
    private $currentDay = 0;
    private $currentMonth = 0;
    private $currentYear = 0;
    private $currentMonthStart = null;
    private $currentMonthDaysLength = null; 

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            '_themename_most_recent_widget',
            esc_html__('Recent Posts', '_themename'),
            ['description' => esc_html__('some description', '_themename')]
        );
        $this->currentYear = date ( "Y", time () );
        $this->currentMonth = date ( "m", time () );

        if (! empty ( $_POST ['year'] )) {
            $this->currentYear = $_POST ['year'];
        }
        if (! empty ( $_POST ['month'] )) {
            $this->currentMonth = $_POST ['month'];
        }
        $this->currentMonthStart = $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-01';
        $this->currentMonthDaysLength = date ( 't', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
    }

    function getCalendarHTML() {
        $calendarHTML = '<div id="calendar-outer">'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<div class="calendar-nav">' . $this->getCalendarNavigation() . '</div>'; 
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-name-title">' . $this->getWeekDayName () . '</ul>';
        $calendarHTML .= '<ul class="week-day-cell">' . $this->getWeekDays () . '</ul>';        
        $calendarHTML .= '</div>';
        return $calendarHTML;
    }

    function getCalendarNavigation() {
        $prevMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart. ' -1 Month'  ) );
        $prevMonthYearArray = explode(",",$prevMonthYear);

        $nextMonthYear = date ( 'm,Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart . ' +1 Month'  ) );
        $nextMonthYearArray = explode(",",$nextMonthYear);

        $navigationHTML = '<div class="prev" data-prev-month="' . $prevMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-prev-year = "' . $prevMonthYearArray[1]. '"><</div>'; 
        $navigationHTML .= '<span id="currentMonth">' . date ( 'M ', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<span contenteditable="true" id="currentYear">'.    date ( 'Y', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) ) . '</span>';
        $navigationHTML .= '<div class="next" data-next-month="' . $nextMonthYearArray[0] . '" data-next-year = "' . $nextMonthYearArray[1]. '">></div>';
        return $navigationHTML;
    }

    function getWeekDayName() {
        $WeekDayName= '';       
        foreach ( $this->weekDayName as $dayname ) {            
            $WeekDayName.= '<li>' . $dayname . '</li>';
        }       
        return $WeekDayName;
    }

    function getWeekDays() {
        $weekLength = $this->getWeekLengthByMonth ();
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart ) );
        $weekDays = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $weekLength; $i ++) {
            for($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j ++) {
                $cellIndex = $i * 7 + $j;
                $cellValue = null;
                if ($cellIndex == $firstDayOfTheWeek) {
                    $this->currentDay = 1;
                }
                if (! empty ( $this->currentDay ) && $this->currentDay <= $this->currentMonthDaysLength) {
                    $cellValue = $this->currentDay;
                    $this->currentDay ++;
                }
                $weekDays .= '<li>' . $cellValue . '</li>';
            }
        }
        return $weekDays;
    }

    function getWeekLengthByMonth() {
        $weekLength =  intval ( $this->currentMonthDaysLength / 7 );    
        if($this->currentMonthDaysLength % 7 > 0) {
            $weekLength++;
        }
        $monthStartDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentMonthStart) );        
        $monthEndingDay= date ( 'N', strtotime ( $this->currentYear . '-' . $this->currentMonth . '-' . $this->currentMonthDaysLength) );
        if ($monthEndingDay < $monthStartDay) {         
            $weekLength++;
        }

        return $weekLength;
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance){
        echo $this->getCalendarHTML();
    }


}

function __themename_register_most_recent_widget(){
    register_widget('__themename_Most_recent_widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', '__themename_register_most_recent_widget');
```

Inside the above class, my widget method, which is what calls the calendar looks like this:

```
public function widget($args, $instance){
    echo $this->getCalendarHTML();
}
```

Until here the calendar shows up with its styling.
How can I get the Javascript and Ajax code to run?

I created a js file named customize-controls.js:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on("click", '.prev', function(event) { 
            var month =  $(this).data("prev-month");
            var year =  $(this).data("prev-year");
            getCalendar(month,year);
        });

        $(document).on("click", '.next', function(event) { 
            var month =  $(this).data("next-month");
            var year =  $(this).data("next-year");
            getCalendar(month,year);
        });
        $(document).on("blur", '#currentYear', function(event) { 
            var month =  $('#currentMonth').text();
            var year = $('#currentYear').text();
            getCalendar(month,year);
        });
    });

    function getCalendar(month,year){
        var url = "/testtheme/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            action : 'calendar_events',
            type: "POST",
            data:'month='+month+'&year='+year,
            success: function(response){
                $("#calendar-html-output").html(response);  
            },
            error: function(){} 
        });
    }
})( jQuery );
```

When I view the calendar and try to click on one of the controls I see the following in my console:

VM3244:1 POST http://localhost/testtheme/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

EDIT:

My functions.php looks like the following:

```
function twentynineteen_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentynineteen-customControl', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-controls.js' ), array('jquery'), '1.1', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'customize-controls-script', 'php_obj',
        array(
            'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentynineteen_scripts' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );
function calendar_events_callback() {

    exit();
}
```

How can I get the javascript side working?

Comment: make sure you also attach the PHP code of the AJAX action

Comment: @cornel.raiu I didnt want to bloat the question with so much, hence I referenced the source for the PhP. But I just updated my answer

Comment: Cool. Writing an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. You never set the `admin-ajax.php` URL like that. You have to use [script localization](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

in your case, where you have the `wp_register_script()` or `wp_enqueue_script()` function you also have to use `wp_localize_script()`.

**PHP File**

Not sure what is your script handle but I will put down an example:

```
wp_enqueue_script('customize-controls-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'customize-controls.js');

wp_localize_script( 'customize-controls-script', 'php_obj',
    array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
);
```

**JS File**

And then in your JS file you use that `php_obj` variable we just sent using `wp_localize_script()`:

```
function getCalendar(month,year){
    var url = php_obj.ajaxUrl;
    $.post({
        url,
        data:{
            action: 'calendar_events',
            month: month,
            year: year
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("#calendar-html-output").html(response);  
        },
        error: function(){} 
    });
}
```

2. You need to add the WP actions to handle the ajax request. You can learn more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

WordPress is usually returning the 400 response when the ajax actions are not set correctly in PHP.

As an example. I will put down a quick sample:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );
function calendar_events_callback() {

    // logic for the output

    // here you output the html you need to the calendar

    // make sure you exit so the output stops when the request is done
    exit();
}
```

Let me know if that is clear or if you need more help with it.

Here is another good reference regarding the [use of AJAX in WP](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

**EDIT**

After the code you added make sure the handle of the `wp_enqueue_script()` is the same as the `wp_localize_script()` one:

```
function twentynineteen_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentynineteen-customControl', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-controls.js' ), array('jquery'), '1.1', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'twentynineteen-customControl', 'php_obj',
        array(
            'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Given the fact that WP does not allow you to instantiate the widget by doing `$calendar_widget = new __themename_Most_recent_widget();`, means that you have to move the PHPCalendar methods in another class that you then instantiate in both the widget and the AJAX call.

That means:

**CalendarWidget class**

```
class CalendarWidget{
    private $weekDayName = array ("MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT","SUN");
    private $currentDay = 0;
    private $currentMonth = 0;
    private $currentYear = 0;
    private $currentMonthStart = null;
    private $currentMonthDaysLength = null;

    function __construct() {

        //method here
    }

    function getCalendarHTML() {
        //method here
    }

    function getCalendarNavigation() {
        //method here
    }

    function getWeekDayName() {
        //method here
    }

    function getWeekDays() {
        //method here
    }

    function getWeekLengthByMonth() {
        //method here
    }
}
```

**Widget Class File**

```
class __themename_Most_recent_widget extends WP_Widget{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            '_themename_most_recent_widget',
            esc_html__('Recent Posts', '_themename'),
            ['description' => esc_html__('some description', '_themename')]
        );
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance){
        $phpCalendar = new CalendarWidget();

        $calendarHTML = $phpCalendar->getCalendarHTML();
        echo $calendarHTML;
    }


}

function __themename_register_most_recent_widget(){
    register_widget('__themename_Most_recent_widget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', '__themename_register_most_recent_widget');
```

**Functions.php**

```
function twentynineteen_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ) );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentynineteen-customControl', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/customize-controls.js' ), array('jquery'), '1.1', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'twentynineteen-customControl', 'php_obj',
        array(
            'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentynineteen_scripts' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_calendar_events', 'calendar_events_callback' );

function calendar_events_callback() {

    $phpCalendar = new CalendarWidget();

    $calendarHTML = $phpCalendar->getCalendarHTML();
    echo $calendarHTML;
    exit();

}
```

This should do it :)

Comment: I just edited my question by adding the enqueue scripts code as well.
Looking at my ajax code, what would be the right "action".
And also how do I call the html for the calendar inside the function you created "calendar_events_callback" ?

Comment: I changed my js to look exactly like the one from your answer and still see the bad request error

Comment: updating the answer now with the changes

Comment: make sure you pull the latest JS in my answer. That should fix the 400 error. Adding some more code to the answer now.

Comment: I copied and pasted you code, but two things that confuse me still is 1 - what to put inside the calendar_events_callback function in the PhP and 2 - The action in the ajax is set to calendar_events. Should that not be calendar_events_callback ?

Comment: Please read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins To set the ajax action you have to use wordpress actions like: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_{your_ajax_action_name}, 'whatever_callback_function_you want')` so you replace `{your_ajax_action_name}` with the value you send through the AJAX `action` in the `data` object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196556/discussion-between-desousa-and-cornel-raiu).

Comment: Support much appreciated